# About an event-listener inside a quiz game

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have a problem with my quiz-game. I was wondering if I need an event-listener if I want to refresh the first page with a question and 4 options. And how that would look like? I am using json to store all the questions.

javascript with my options and question from the first page:

`let question = document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = quiz.quests[0].question;
let answer1 = document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = quiz.quests[0].answer[0].alt;
let answer2 = document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = quiz.quests[0].answer[1].alt;
let answer3 = document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = quiz.quests[0].answer[2].alt;
let answer4 = document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML = quiz.quests[0].answer[3].alt;`

```
<div id="wrapper_questions">
<div class="background">
    <div class="grid">
        <div id="question">
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
        <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">

        <div id="choices">
            <input type="checkbox" id="choice1"><span id="answer1"></span>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="choice2"><span id="answer2"></span>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="choice3"><span id="answer3"></span>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="choise4"><span id="answer4"></span>
        </div>
        <hr style="margin-bottom: 50px">

        <button onclick="nextQuestion()" >Next</button>
        <br>
        <footer>
                <p  id="progress">Question x of y.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an event listener that simply alerts when a choice is selected. Perhaps this will help you get started.

```js
let choices = document.getElementById("choices");
choices.addEventListener('click', (event)=>
{
  console.log(event.target.id);

});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper_questions">
<div class="background">
    <div class="grid">
        <div id="question">
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
        <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">

        <div id="choices">
            <input type="radio" id="choice1" name="choiceForQuestion1"><span id="answer1">Answer 1</span>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" id="choice2" name="choiceForQuestion1"><span id="answer2">Answer 2</span>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" id="choice3" name="choiceForQuestion1"><span id="answer3">Answer 3</span>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" id="choise4" name="choiceForQuestion1"><span id="answer4">Answer 4</span>
        </div>
        <hr style="margin-bottom: 50px">

        <button onclick="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
        <br>
        <footer>
                <p  id="progress">Question x of y.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, if the choices are mutually exclusive, I'd use a [radio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) instead of check boxes.

Comment: thank you! the thing is that i want the questions to have multiple right answers and i dont believe radio buttons will work then?

Comment: maybe a function nextQuestion? more like onclick = "nextQuestion()" ?? i know ive already have written that but i havent made a function for that, do you have any suggestioins??

Comment: In the html, give the next button an id attribute, so that you can use document.getElementById like I did for the choices div. Then you can add an 'click' event listener to the button (just like I did with the choices div). Inside that code you can [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the questions and answers with a newly created choices div, upon clicking the next button. The key thing you need to learn about is called [DOM modification](https://www.google.com/search?q=DOM+modification).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have time to do much more than point you in the right direction. Watch a few [videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=modifying+dom), and I'm sure you'll understand what to do after that.